# the post dispatch won't show up in redux, try gets the output but then catch throws an error and invalidates the token. It's an old codebase

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have been trying to refactor it , we have an async await function receiving credentials from the form component file which dispatches the credentials onSubmit

```
dispatch(submitLogin(credentials));
```

the submitLogin function is an exported async function with a try catch block

```
  try {
    //post login credentials
    const res = await axios.post("seller/auth/login", credentials);
    
    //extract token from data
    const token = res.data.data.token;
    //store token in local storage
    localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    //set token
    setToken(token);
    
    const decoded = {
      name: res.data.data.name,
      id: res.data.data.id,
    };

    const decodedJwt = jwt_decode(token);
  
    localStorage.setItem("id", decoded.id);
    localStorage.setItem("types", decodedJwt.types);
    localStorage.setItem("sellerName", decoded.name);

    const secondResponse = await axios.get("seller/auth/check-token",{
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }); 
    localStorage.setItem("isItValid", secondResponse.data.message);
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ERRORS,
      payload: {},
    });
    dispatch({
      type: SET_CURR_SELLER,
      payload: decoded,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ERRORS,
      payload: error,
    });
  }
```

when I console.log(action) from reducers file it only logs GET_ERRORS
and the error message says
**Invalid token specified: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')**

Comment: The try/catch block does its job so you need to find where this `replace` is to understand where the problem comes from. Maybe in the functions `setToken` or `jwt_decode`? Is token `undefined`?

Comment: there is no replace keyword in the files I am working on. It is indeed invalidating the token and throwing an error but I don't know what is making it skip the set_curr_seller @Arkellys

Comment: Just put `console.log` to debug. Is `res` okay? Is `token` okay? Does `decodedJwt` returns the correct result? And so on until you find the place where it breaks.

Comment: I did everything, except the dispatch for set_curr_seller everthing seems working @Arkellys

Comment: From what I read of your error it is probably returned by `jwt_decode`

Comment: Assuming you're using the library `jwt-decode`, see [this](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/issues/65#issuecomment-852076626). If you look at the source code, you probably get the error from [this line](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/blob/910b79f8862dead864a957576913aadb10cb696a/lib/index.js#L20). And if you look at the function, [here is the replace](https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode/blob/910b79f8862dead864a957576913aadb10cb696a/lib/base64_url_decode.js#L16) or maybe it's the one from L5. So, the token is invalid, as the error says.